# Blueprintjs Select keyboard navigation not working - React

Tags: reactjs, select, accessibility, blueprintjs

I have a blueprintjs select component and I was wondering how to enable keyboard navigation on the component. I followed their documentation but couldn't get a better understanding of it. Is it an issue with itemRendered modifier prop? Please advice.

Below is the link I have implemented using blueprintjs select:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-w12ule)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wire up `onActiveItemChange` to update the value you're using for `activeItem` on the Select as so:

```
<CountrySelect
  items={countryCodes || []}
  onItemSelect={handleItemSelect}
  activeItem={selectedCountry}
  onActiveItemChange={setSelectedCountry}
  {...CountrySelectProps}
  noResults={<MenuItem disabled={true} text="No results." />}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to implement `onActiveItemChange`

as per documentation here:
https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/multi-select

example:
https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/docs-app/src/examples/select-examples/multiSelectExample.tsx

ensure your item renderer you set `active={modifiers.active}`:

```
 private renderFilm: ItemRenderer<IFilm> = (film, { modifiers, handleClick }) => {
        if (!modifiers.matchesPredicate) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <MenuItem
                active={modifiers.active}
```